# Connection blocked because server only allows public key authentication. Please contact your network administrator

Tags: networking, server, ssh

I am experiencing a global issue with all my Ubuntu VMs in AWS. When trying to connect my VM with:

```
ssh -i "~/pk/BC-DEV1.pem" ubuntu@52.47.167.xxx
```

I cannot connect anymore with my VMs. Even worse, when I create a new VM in AWS, with fresh private key, it won't work neither.

I get the message:

```
The authenticity of host '52.47.167.xxx (52.47.167.xxx)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:cI74OcCXlfwygceYo4v3wcMGUDnA2yCLSiVbj0X8cCg.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
Warning: Permanently added '52.47.167.xxx' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Received disconnect from 52.47.167.xxx port 22:2: Connection blocked because server only allows public key authentication. Please contact your network administrator.
Disconnected from 52.47.167.xxx port 22
```

I have this issue at work, not in other site, nor with 4G connection.

I contacted my admin, that told me that static IP address had changed, but nothing more.

I already checked the `/var/log/auth.log`, but nothing is showing up.

What should I do ? I just can't work anymore!!!

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it viewing [this page](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=305575):

with this comment:

> Finally the problem was our Firewall. After an upgrade a ssh_certificate_deep_inspection feature got activated and caused all the problems.